# yii2 how to replace customize meta tag from "view" with default meta tags in "layout"

Tags: php, html, yii2

I want to put default meta data description tag for main template layout.

There are many cases where I needed to replace the default meta tags like description and keywords with customize data in views.

I have tried:

```
$this->registerMetaTag
```

In views where I need to customize the meta tags and also I have used this in main layout.

I thought if I would use meta tags with their id or name it would be replaced but the result shows duplicate meta tags like e.g.

```
<meta id="main_index" name="Description" content="my default content added by layout.">


<meta id="main_index" name="Description" content="my customized content added by the view"></head>
```

What is the best way to provide default description tag but can be customize by views whenever I call `$this->registerMetaTag`

Comment: Note that Yii will only manage the tags that it has generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it my self , since my objective was not to repeat on each action a default keywords or other meta tags, but places where i would like to replace i would use registerMetaTag in action.

- First create your own extended version of Controller like below

  ```
  class MyController extends Controller
  {    
      public function beforeAction($event){
      $this->view->title = Yii::$app->params['pageTitle'];

      \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['pageDefaultDescription'],"default_description");
      \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['pageDefaultKeywords'],"default_keywords");
      \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['pageDefaultAuthor'],"default_author");

      // Open Graph Tags
      \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['pageDefaultOG_Description'],"default_og_description");
      \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['pageDefaultOG_SiteName'],"default_og_sitename");
      \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['pageDefaultOG_Title'],"default_og_title");
      \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['pageDefaultOG_Type'],"default_og_type");


      return parent::beforeAction($event);
      }
  }
  ```
- So now all the customized keywords author etc meta tags can be added from the config file of param as a default.
- Now any new controller you create just extend that with MyController so by default all the above meta tags will be attached.
- If you need to replace the meta tag or customize in some actions then do like below.

  ```
   public function actionIndex()
  {


      \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
          'name' => 'description',
          'content' => 'my customize description for the index.',
          'id'=>"main_index"
      ],"main_index"); //this will now replace the default one.


      return $this->render('index');
  }
  ```

Comment: I've used the above solutions getting error Undefined index: pageTitle

Answer (score 11):

Here's my solution which is much simpler without redundant controller.
All you need is to define default tags in app params and overwrite them in view.

**config/params.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'og_title' => ['property' => 'og:title', 'content' => 'title'],
    'og_description' => ['property' => 'og:description', 'content' => 'description'],
    'og_url' => ['property' => 'og:url', 'content' => '/'],
    'og_image' => ['property' => 'og:image', 'content' => 'image']
];
```

**views/layouts/main.php**

```
<?php
    $this->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['og_title'], 'og_title');
    $this->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['og_description'], 'og_description');
    $this->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['og_url'], 'og_url');
    $this->registerMetaTag(Yii::$app->params['og_image'], 'og_image');
?>
```

Now if I need to set custom tags I overwrite params in my view

**views/site/index.php**

```
<?php
    Yii::$app->params['og_title']['content'] = 'custom title';
    Yii::$app->params['og_description']['content'] = 'custom desc';
    Yii::$app->params['og_url']['content'] = '/new/url';
    Yii::$app->params['og_image']['content'] = 'image.jpg';
?>
```

Comment: Great and simple solution! This should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: i am not getting the meta tags printed in the layout file.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage registered meta tag by using a similar id. Ensure that the meta tags are generated using Yii. From your question you already have generated a meter tag which is impossible to replace since Yii is not managing it.

```
public function actionTest1{
    $this->registerMetaTag('your example', 'description', null, array(), 'metaDescription');
    $this->render('myView');
}

public function actionTest2{
    $this->registerMetaTag('your example2', 'description', null, array(), 'metaDescription');
    $this->render('myView2');
}
```

Comment: @Bobulous this edits are wrong kindly revert http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerMetaTag-detail

Comment: I don't think I made the edit to which you refer, and it looks like you've now reverted the edit you feel was incorrect. (You can see the edit history by clicking on the "edited" or "edited by" link to the left of the name of the person who posted the question or answer.)